# Jquery change event doesn't fire every time

Tags: jquery

I have some jquery code to fire on input-change:

```
$("[data-binding] input").bind('change', function () {
    debug('changing');
    PerformWCFCall($(this));
});
```

the `debug`-function is simply a call to `console.log`

The problem is that it randomly doesn't fire. 90% of the time everything works fine, but then all of a sudden it stops working a couple of times, and starts working again.

the `PerformWCFCall` doesn't contain any binding-code, but only a async call to a WCF service.

I'm also calling  `$("[data-binding] input").unbind('change')` before the call to `.bind` just in case. But I'm having a hard time figuring this one out.

Hope someone can help

Let me know if you need any more information!

Comment: Does it happen in a certain browser?  Could you show more of your markup/code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure `PerformWCFCall` dont modify nodes selected with `$("[data-binding] input")` , if it does than use `live()` in place of `bind()`

Answer (score 0):

What does 'PerformWCFCall' do with the input? Does it replace it? - If so, try using 'live' instead of bind....or rebind after the call to 'PerformWCFCall'.

Comment: PerformWCFCall might replace the input indeed... I did try with live, but that didn't help... I'll try to rebind after PerformWCFCall..

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery selector looks suspicious, are you trying to bind on input elements that has a property called data-binding? If so you should use this selector instead:

```
$('input[data-binding]')
```

I see someone already suggested the live event, so i'm wondering when you do the binding - is it after document.ready?

Also if you're using FireFox - install FireBug if you haven't already (or use IE developer tools for IE, or the debugger in chrome) to see if the handler stops working (the 10% of the time) after a javascript error - it could be part of the WCF call gone wrong. Also install fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to inspect the traffic from your client to your WCF service. Something gone wrong here can halt the exection of your javascript.

Comment: The $('[data-binding] input') is because I want it to apply to all input-elements that are children of some element with the attribute data-binding set :)

Comment: Okay ;) You really should look into the javascript errors. 90% of the time when something doesn't work periodically on my side, it's because the javascript had an error somewhere...